# Sectioning or cutting my 3D Object Horizontally (3D cross section) with ARKit or else in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

It's my first time working with Augmented Reality and ARKit.

I want to know if I am missing something, I've been looking for a solution for a long time.

What I would like to do is sectioning my 3D house horizontally so I can see my house floor by floor or sectioning the house by Y height; like it's shown in these two images from the CAD Exchanger software. I've seen some applications using this tool, but I couldn't find a way to do it. ( PS: I have a 3D house implemented by AutoCAD)

Is there any idea how is it possible to do it? using code or using third-party libraries? Any hint will be appreciated to even direct my next research because I am lost at this point and I don't know if it is even feasible. Any help? thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can achieve this using OpenGL feature glClipPlane. You can define a plane and OpenGL will allow you to clip all objects outside of the plane. You can define multiple planes as well. To achieve the same in SceneKit, you need to add custom OpenGL commands

Comment: Thank you @codetiger for your answer! can I still use the OpenGL feature even I don't know the exact height where I need to do a horizontal cross-section?