# ARKit and SceneKit – Can I see through 3D objects in my scene?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to figure out how to see objects which are inside a "nested" 3D object.

For example, let's say I have a 3D living room object with high walls that I can't see inside of it. But my application requirements actually see inside that object and see the couch, the television...

All the example I've seen on the internet or on this website are dealing with simple 3D objects
hope I was clear enough to understand what I am actually talking about.

or is there a solution to this question? (3D cross section) which I posted it a day ago.

[Sectioning or cutting my 3D Object Horizontally (3D cross section) with ARKit or else in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63282955/sectioning-or-cutting-my-3d-object-horizontally-with-arkit-or-else-in-swift)

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Elin. Please share a video example (how you want it to be). It's quite difficult to understand what you want precisely.